# How to display child Window icon in task bar

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2

```
Window {
    Window {
        id: childWindow
    }
}
```

I have a QML like this, and `childWindow` icon does not display in task bar when the window is shown. My environment is Windows 7.
In a CPP setting I think it would suffice to set parent of `childWindow` to `0` to have both windows to be top level.

But how to do that in QML?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like that:

```
Item
{
    Window
    {
        id: wnd1
        width: 200
        height: 200
        title: "Window1"
        visible: true
        onClosing: wnd2.close();
    }

    Window
    {
        id: wnd2
        width: 200
        height: 200
        title: "Window2"
        visible: true
    }
}
```

Note that when `wnd1` is closed (main/root window) also the second one gets closed `onClosing` handle ensuring the correct - or expected - behaviour on main window closing.

Answer (score 2):

If you create an Object in QML like this, the *parent* is automatically set, and you can only change the *visual parent* by using the `parent`-property.

To have it otherwise, you might do one of the following:

- Use JS Dynamic Object Creation.
- Load multiple QML-Files in C++

The former can be done as follows:

```
property Window mySecondWindow: secondWindowComponent.createObject(null)
Component {
    id: secondWindowComponent
    Window {
        ...
    }
}
```

To destroy this, call `mySecondWindow.destroy()`. If you only delete the reference, the JS GC will eventually take care of it. If it does not fail.

The latter can be done by adding something like that to your `main.cpp`

```
engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml")));
engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml")));
engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml")));
```